# Como adicionar a condição WHERE no SELECT da tabela com server-side processing?

Tags: mysql, select, where, lado-do-servidor

Queria adicionar uma pequena condição no SELECT da minha tabela, mas estou utilizando o server-side processing do DataTables para listar os registros pelo lado do servidor. Tentei adaptar o código padrão do DataTables para adicionar essa condição mas não consegui, alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Linha que quero incluir no SELECT da tabela:**

```
WHERE id_status = 'Ativo'
```

**ssp.class.php**

```
/**
     * The difference between this method and the `simple` one, is that you can
     * apply additional `where` conditions to the SQL queries. These can be in
     * one of two forms:
     *
     * * 'Result condition' - This is applied to the result set, but not the
     *   overall paging information query - i.e. it will not effect the number
     *   of records that a user sees they can have access to. This should be
     *   used when you want apply a filtering condition that the user has sent.
     * * 'All condition' - This is applied to all queries that are made and
     *   reduces the number of records that the user can access. This should be
     *   used in conditions where you don't want the user to ever have access to
     *   particular records (for example, restricting by a login id).
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array|PDO $conn PDO connection resource or connection parameters array
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  string $whereResult WHERE condition to apply to the result set
     *  @param  string $whereAll WHERE condition to apply to all queries
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function complex ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );
        $localWhereResult = array();
        $localWhereAll = array();
        $whereAllSql = '';

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        $whereResult = self::_flatten( $whereResult );
        $whereAll = self::_flatten( $whereAll );

        if ( $whereResult ) {
            $where = $where ?
                $where .' AND '.$whereResult :
                'WHERE '.$whereResult;
        }

        if ( $whereAll ) {
            $where = $where ?
                $where .' AND '.$whereAll :
                'WHERE '.$whereAll;

            $whereAllSql = 'WHERE '.$whereAll;
        }

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table` ".
            $whereAllSql
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
                intval( $request['draw'] ) :
                0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problema solucionado com sucesso!** Era mais simples do que eu imaginava devido ao avanço do DataTables, mas vou deixar a solução abaixo caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida. No arquivo ssp.class.php possui uma linha que começa com "$where", no meu arquivo é na linha 207, apenas adicione sua condição dentro das aspas e JÁ ERA!

**ssp.class.php : Linha 207**

```
// Combine the filters into a single string
$where = 'protocolo_status = "Ativo"';
```